# Import CSV into Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, web

Have a question. I'm currently trying to import a single column CSV and import it into an array via Javascript. I'm quite a noob programmer so to speak, at the moment, I've tried to modify the code for what I believe works for me as per https://www.webslesson.info/2017/04/csv-file-to-html-table-using-ajax-jquery.html, however have had no success. Just looking for suggestions as to how I can approach this task.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide code example and explain what exactly is not working for you. Good luck!

Comment: In order to help please share some data sample in this case your target csv and the expected output in JSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery-csv](https://github.com/typeiii/jquery-csv) library for converting `CSV to array`